# Java JApplet - Trying to switch JPanels created in external class

Tags: java, jpanel, switch-statement, japplet

I have a class that extends jApplet and three classes that are extend jpanel. Now, i am trying to switch these jPanels on actions taken from JButtons with a specific Jpanel.

Problem: I am able to load/display the first panel in my applet that i have set visible from the applet itself in the init() method. But, when i try to do the same from the button click on the jPanel form it does not work. Me panel gets closed but the new panel added does not display.

Code Context of the code below:

1. Application. java is the applet class
2. User_Login. java is the jpanel class (1)
3. Reset_Password.java is the jpanel class(2)

On click of the Change Password button on the User_Login jpanel, i want to invoke the Reset_Password jpanel.

The code is as below. Any help is highly appreciated

Application.java

```
package business_intelligence;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


/**
 *
 * @author lokesh
 */
public class Application extends JApplet {

int x = 0;

Container content_pane = getContentPane();

User_Login obj = new User_Login();
Reset_Password obj1 = new Reset_Password();



public void init() {

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1200, 1000);
   content_pane.add(obj);
   content_pane.add(obj1);
   content_pane.add(obj2);
   add(obj1);
   add(obj2);
   add(obj);
   obj.setVisible(true);
   obj1.setVisible(false);
   obj2.setVisible(false);
}

public void Change()
{
    content_pane.removeAll();
    content_pane.add(obj1);
    add(obj1);
    obj1.setVisible(true);
}
public void Login()
{
    content_pane.removeAll();
    content_pane.add(obj);
    add(obj);
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

User_Login.java

```
package business_intelligence;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
/**
 *
 * @author lokesh
 */
public class User_Login extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
FlowLayout f;
JLabel l1;
JLabel l2, l3, h1 ;
JButton b1;
JButton b2,b3,b4;
Font fo1 = new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,25);
Font fo2 = new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,15);
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
JPasswordField tp1 = new JPasswordField();
Color bg = new Color (255,255,204);

public User_Login()
{

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1200, 1000);
    setBackground(bg);
    setLayout(null);
    h1 = new JLabel("Welcome to Business Intelligence Application -- Login");
 h1.setFont(fo1);
 h1.setBounds(100, 02, 800, 50);
 l1 = new JLabel("User-name");
 l1.setFont(fo2);
 l2 = new JLabel("Password");
 l2.setFont(fo2);
 l3 = new JLabel();
 l3.setFont(fo2);
 l3.setForeground(Color.RED);
 b1 = new JButton("Submit");
 b2 = new JButton("Close");
 b3 = new JButton("Reset Password");
 b4 = new JButton("New User Request");
 add(h1);
 l1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 40);
 add(l1);
 l2.setBounds(100, 150, 100, 40);
 add (l2);
 add(b1);
 add(b2);
 tf1.setBounds(300, 100, 200, 40);
 add(tf1);
 tp1.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 40);
 add(tp1);
 b1.setBounds(25, 260, 150, 50);
 add(b1);
 b2.setBounds(200, 260, 150, 50);
 add(b2);
 l3.setBounds(100, 200, 400, 50);
 add(l3);
 b3.setBounds(375, 260, 150, 50);
 add(b3);
 b4.setBounds(550, 260, 160, 50);
 add(b4);
 b1.addActionListener(this);
 b2.addActionListener(this);
 b3.addActionListener(this);
 b4.addActionListener(this);

}

public void verifyLogin()
{

    String uid = tf1.getText();
    char ch[] = tp1.getPassword();
    String pwd = String.valueOf(ch);

    Connect obj1 = new Connect();
    obj1.connect();
    int r = obj1.verifyLogin(uid, pwd);
    if (r ==1)
    {
        setVisible(false);
        Application obj = new Application();
        obj.Dashboard();

    }
    else
    {
        l3.setText("Incorrect User-name or Password. Try again.");
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    Object ob = evt.getSource();
    if(ob == b1)
        verifyLogin();
    else if (ob == b2)
            System.exit(0);   
    else if (ob == b3)
    {   
        setVisible(false);
        Application obj = new Application();
        obj.Change();  
    }

}

}
```

Reset_Password.java

```
package business_intelligence;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

//mport java.awt.event.*;
/**
 *
 * @author lokesh
 */
public class Reset_Password extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

String email;
String pwd;
String cpwd;
JLabel l1,l2, l3,l4, h1 ;
JButton b1;
JButton b2;
Font fo3 = new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,25);
Font fo4 = new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,15);
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
JPasswordField p1 = new JPasswordField();
JPasswordField p2 = new JPasswordField();
int r;

Color bg = new Color (255,255,204);



public Reset_Password()
{
    setSize(1200, 1000);
    setBackground(bg);
    setLayout(null);
    h1 = new JLabel("Welcome to Business Intelligence Application -- Change Password");
    h1.setFont(fo3);
    h1.setBounds(100, 02, 1000, 50);
    add(h1);
    l1 = new JLabel("E-mail");
    l1.setFont(fo4);
    l2 = new JLabel("New Password");
    l2.setFont(fo4);
    l3 = new JLabel("Confirm Password");
    l3.setFont(fo4);
    l4 = new JLabel("");
    l4.setFont(fo4);
    l4.setForeground(Color.RED);
    b1 = new JButton("Submit");
    b2 = new JButton("Cancel");
    l1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 40);
    add(l1);
    l2.setBounds(100, 150, 100, 40);
    add (l2);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    tf1.setBounds(300, 100, 200, 40);
    add(tf1);
    p1.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 40);
    add(p1);
    p2.setBounds(300, 200, 200, 40);
    add(p2);
    l3.setBounds(100, 200, 400, 50);
    add(l3);
    l4.setBounds(100, 250, 400, 50);
    add(l4);
    b1.setBounds(100, 300, 150, 50);
    add(b1);
    b2.setBounds(350, 300, 150, 50);
    add(b2);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)       
{                                         

    Object ob = e.getSource();
    if(ob == b1)    
        resetPassword();
    if (ob == b2)
    { 

           Application obj = new Application ();
           obj.Login();
    }

}

    // TODO add your handling code here                                        

/*private void ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    //setVisible(false);

    if (isVisible()== true)
        setVisible(false);

    this.remove(this);
    Business_Intelligence obj = new Business_Intelligence();
    obj.activated();

} */     



public void resetPassword()
{

    email = tf1.getText();
    char ch[] = p1.getPassword();
    pwd = String.valueOf(ch);
    char ch1[] = p2.getPassword();
    cpwd = String.valueOf(ch1);
    if (ch.length >= 8)
    {

        if(pwd.equals(cpwd))
        {
        Connect obj = new Connect();
        obj.connect();
        int r = obj.verifyEmail(email);
        if (r==1)
            {
                obj.connect();
                obj.updat(email, pwd);
                l4.setVisible(true);
                l4.setText("password changed");              
                p1.setText(null);
                p2.setText(null);
                tf1.setText(null);

            }
        if (r==0)
            {
                l4.setVisible(true);
                l4.setText("incorrect e-mail id");
            }
        }
        if(!pwd.equals(cpwd))
        {
        //jLabel5.setForeground(Color.RED);
        l4.setVisible(true);
        l4.setText("password and confirm password did not match");     
        } 
    }
    if (ch.length < 8)
    {
     //jLabel5.setForeground(Color.RED);   
     l4.setVisible(true);
     l4.setText("password should be a minimum of 8 characters");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly putting then in your applet ContentPane, you should put a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) in that ContentPane and then change the visible panel of that CardLayout, which is a far simpler operation.

**EDIT** An example

OK, let's consider you want to put a CardLayout in your ContentPane, then add all other panels to it.

For that, you'll simply change your init method as such :

```
public void init() {

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1200, 1000);

    // Shamelessely borrowed from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html
    // which you SHOULD definitevely read
    content_pane.setLayout(new CardLayout());

    // First item will stay visible, as long as it is not changed
    content_pane.add(obj, "user_login");
    content_pane.add(obj1, "user_panel");
    content_pane.add(obj2, "reset_login");

}
```

Then, when user logs in, and you have to change your active panel, change your Change method as such

```
public void Login()
{
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) content_pane.getLayout();
    card.show(content_pane, "user_panel");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, can u give a quick example of how to go about it?

Comment: @Lokesh hopefully internet has absolutely no content regarding CardLayout usage, nor has [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+cardlayout).

Answer (score 0):

```
japplet.setSize ( panel.getWidth (), panel.getHeight () );
japplet.setContentPane ( panel );
panel.revalidate ();
panel.repaint ();
japplet.revalidate ();
japplet.repaint ();
revalidate () must be called first prior repaint ();
source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119069/repaint-jpanel-doesnt-work-in-japplet
```